# Elasticsearch/Painless: sort based on how many elements the array field incudes

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'd like to sort documents based on how many strings "London", "Paris", "Tokyo" are included in `cities` field.

```
["London", "Paris", "Tokyo"]<- this includes all of them, so this is the first.
["London", "Paris", "Shanghai"]<- this includes two of them, so this is the second.
["London", "Rome", "Shanghai"]<- this includes only one of them, so this is the third.
["LA", "Rome", "Shanghai"]<- this includes none of them, so this is the last.
```

I tried to achieve this using script clause for hours, but couldn't even make a dent. For the document of painless is so limited on the internet, I haven't the least idea of how to do this.

If you share some information about this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did it.

```
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
          double score = 0;
          for(city in params._source['cities']){
            for(target in params.targets){
              if(city == target){
                score += 1;
              }
            }
          }
          return score;
        """,
        "params": {
          "targets": ["London","Paris","Tokyo"]
        }
      },
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).